# Reading array of characters from file into a 2 dimensional array

Tags: c, fopen

I'm having trouble in the following methods when trying to read equations (like 3 +5 /6) into a 2 dimensional array from a file with 10 equations.

```
int count=1;
void read(){
  int i;
  int j;
  FILE *file = fopen("C:\\Users\\Sara\\Desktop\\Project2\\input", "r");

  if(file == NULL){
    printf("Unable to open file");
  }else{
    while(!feof(file)){
      for (i=0; i <=20; i++){
        for (j=0;j<=100;j++){
          if (fscanf(file,"%c", &array[i][j]) < 1) break;
          printf("Equation %d : %s \n", count, array[i]);
          count++;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: Could you please describe what your trouble is? You seem to read all lines into the `array[0]`, because you `break` only on the end of the file. You should also check for new-line characters `'\n'`. And consider using `getc` instead of `fscanf` for reading characters. Or, rather, consider using `fgets`.

Comment: @MOehm How can I make it store each equation in a different index? and where should I check for the new-line characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues with your code:

- You don't show how array is defined, but I assume it is `array[20][100]`. Valid inices are therfore 0 to 19 and 0 to 100 respectively, the upper bound is exclusive in C. Your loops look like `(i = 0; i <= 20; i++)` and include that bound and therefore might address the illegal array indices 20 and 100.
- A text file contains non-zero characters. Line breaks are indicated by the the new-line character with ASCII code 10, which in C can be written as `'\n'`.
- Strings in C are arrays of `char` that are terminated with a null character. You never terminate your strings. Nearly all standard string routines require strings to be zero-terminated and will therefore not produce the desired results when they are called with your array. (You also need to keep in mind to leave space for the terimating null character.)
- While `fscanf(file, "%c", &c)` can be used to read single characters, the standard character-reading function `c = getc(file)` has less overhead and is easier to understand at first glance.
- `for` loops are usually used when the length of an array is known. You don't know how many equations you have and how long each equation is. A `while` loop might be better.
- I guess the you `count` variable counts the equations. Because you increament it in the inner loop, you count the total amount of characters that are read.
- You read and overwrite the lines over and over again, because you check for `feof` in the outer loop: Read 20 lines; notice that the file hasn't reached its end; try to read 20 more lines into the same data, and so on. (Advice: Don't use `feof`; it usually doesn't do what you want. Instead, check the return values of the reading functions. For example, `fscanf` will return `EOF` if the end of the file was found.)
- Minor quibble: When printing error messages, you should print them to `stderr`. Also, be sure to terminate them with a new-line character for tidy printing. t's also a good idea to include the file name in the message.

Putting all this together:

```
int read(const char *fn)
{
    int i, j;
    FILE *file = fopen(fn, "r");

    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file %s.\n", fn);
        return -1;
    }

    i = 0;
    j = 0;

    while (i < 20) {
        int c = getc(file);

        if (c == EOF) {
            /* End of file: stop reading */
            array[i][j] = '\0';
            break;
        }

        if (c == '\n') {
            /* New line: Begin new line and reset column counter */
            array[i][j] = '\0';
            j = 0;
            i++;
        } else {
            if (j < 100 - 1) array[i][j++] = c;
        }
    }

    fclose(file);        
    return i;
}
```

This function takes the file name as argument and returns the number of equations that were read. When the file could not be opened, it returns the special value -1. It reads into a global array with hardcoded sizes, however.

Comment: what if I want to use the equations in another function?

Comment: As in your code, `array` is a global variable that you can access from elsewhere in the same file.

Comment: I'm trying to make a function that goes over the equations and checks if they are valid or not but it doesn't take except the first equation
         void checkErrors(char array[20][100]){
    int l;
    int m;
    for(l=0; l<20; l++){
    for(m=0; m<100; m++){
        if((array[l][m]=='$'))
            printf("Equation is invalid");
            else
                printf("%s", array);
    }
    }
}

Comment: Please, learn more about strings before asking for help here. Again, there's so much that is wrong. (1) Do not loop over fixed bounds. `l` should run up to `count` (or the return value of `read`); the loop over `m` should stop after encountering the terinating null. All chacatres after that will likely contain garabge and might well have a dollar sign in them. (2) The `%s` format for strings expects a C string, i.e. `char *` as argument. You pass `array`, which is `char[20][100]` or `char (*)[100]`; please pass `array[l]`. (3) Don't print the whole string (repeatedly) in the inner loop.

Comment: I don't know what exactly you are trying to do, but maybe it's easier to process the equations one at a time: read one equation, check it, evaluate it. Read next equation, and so on. That way you'd be dealing with one-dimensional car arrays, which might be a lot clearer.

Comment: That is what I'm trying to do but I don't know how to check each element in one equation at a time